# Alterar favicon em um projeto Wamp

Tags: html, front-end, favicon

Usei o seguinte código dentro do  para alterar o favicon do meu projeto

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
```

Deu certo no index, mas ao inserir o mesmo codigo nas outras páginas o favicon continua sendo o padrão do Wamp.

Ps. o diretório das paginas são os mesmos, então o link está direcionando para a mesma imagem, dentro da mesma pasta (img).

Alguém consegue enxergar uma luz para o meu problema?

Meu codigo está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei por qual motivo o código inserido que altera o favicon só esta sendo reconehcido na página index. A imagem a seguir foi postada apenas para mostrar que o navegador não reconhece o codigo em questão:

Nas demais paginas ele não reconhece a linha de codigo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara o Favicon costuma ficar no Cash, tenta limpar o cash para ver se resolve

Comment: ja limpei. Apaguei o histórico do navegador selecionando todas as opções

Comment: Já que vc está declarando o arquivo como .ico tente declara o Type dele na tag. Assim: <link rel="shortcut icon" TYPE="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" /> as vezes resolve...

Comment: Amigo *sem o link do favicon fica difícil*.... Pq vc não posta a imagem da `<head>` já com o link do favicon certinho?

Comment: Foi postado para a conferencia.

Comment: tem algo errado na segunda imagem nao com diz com a primeira, a header tem somente 2 css ja no seu html tem 3 css, 2 script, icon...

Comment: A segunda imagem é um print do CTRL + U no navegador. Por isso é normal o javascript não parecer. Mas deveria aparecer o icon. Se não está aparecendo é porque o navegador não está reconhecendo o codigo. E é este o meu problema

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque o próprio navegador tenta sozinho procurar a imagem `favicon.ico` na pasta root do seu site ou localhost. Isto ocorre geralmente ocorre no Safari e no Chrome (nos demais navegadores não notei este comportamento), então quando **não define** o:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="...."/>
```

O navegador sozinho vai tentar procurar o `http://localhost/favicon.ico` ou `http://site.com/favicon.ico`

O que pode fazer é colocar na pasta root do Wamp o seu favicon e limpar o cache do navegador, ou simplesmente pode criar um include via PHP e adicionar em todas páginas:

header.php:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="...caminho do favicon..."/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

E em todas paginas adicionar:

```
<head>
  <title>Meu titulo</title>
  <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</head>
```

### Caminhos relativos vs absolutos

O caminho relativo é aquele que carrega em relação ao caminho da página atual, então se estiver na página

```
 http://localhost/pagina.php
```

Ele vai procurar o favicon em:

```
 http://localhost/img/favicon.ico
```

se estiver na página

```
 http://localhost/foo/bar/baz/pagina.php
```

Ele vai procurar o favicon em:

```
 http://localhost/foo/bar/baz/img/favicon.ico
```

Ou seja é o caminho errado, então para evitar isto adicione o caminho completo (absoluto) do favicon, por exemplo:

header.php:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/img/favicon.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

No entanto se você for enviar para um servidor, isto não irá funcionar então terá que trocar o endereço, no caso você pode usar somente o caminho absoluto, sem o HTTP, colocando uma barra na frente assim `/img/favicon.ico`, desta forma ele vai procurar a partir do root, exemplo:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Na verdade a unica coisa que alterou da sua sugestão no meu código foi retirar a linha em cada pagina e inserir dentro do header.php. Mesmo assim eu fiz as alterações, mas não resolveu. Continua a mesma coisa. E sim, eu limpei o cache do navegador

Comment: @Amauri abra em uma aba anonima e veja se ainda ocorre. Provavelmente o caminho do favicon no teu HTML esta relativo e não absoluto

Comment: modo anonimo continua a mesma coisa

Comment: @Amauri veja a edição da resposta

Comment: Eu coloquei o caminho absoluto, e continua a mesma coisa. O problema não é na referencia a imagem, pois todas as paginas se encontram no mesmo diretório.

Comment: @Amauri abra o console do navegador e veja se ocorre algum erro, confira se todas paginas realmente foram salvas, confira se o PHP esta usando XCache ou Opcache (que não tem nada haver com cache do navegador) ... Confira o codigo fonte gerado no navegador das paginas com problema apertando Ctrl+U. Com certeza vc fez alguma confusão.

Comment: Conforme postei acima, o navegador não está reconhecendo a linha de código que altera o favicon. O estranho é que no index ele reconhece.

Comment: @Amauri olha a sua imagem https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq7i9.png, dentro do head não tem nenhuma tag LINK. Como eu disse, você deve estar fazendo alguma confusão na hora de salvar.

Comment: Não amigo, essa imagem é do f12 no navegador. No código foi inserido, e foi salvo. Não sei por qual motivo o navegador é que não está reconhecendo. Vou postar a imagem do codigo completo, e salvo. –

Comment: @Amauri eu sei que é do navegador, eu trabalho com isso, eu sei a diferença de um console de navegador pra um editor de texto amigo. O problema é que se no console do navegador não aparece a TAG LINK é porque não esta lá mesmo, por isso que disse que vc se confundiu em algo, se confundir é quando vc pensa que fez algo certo, mas se enganou, você pode estar convicto de que fez tudo ok, mas o resultado não aparece é porque tem algo errado.

Comment: @Amauri Esse 192.168.1.220 é o seu computador ou é outro computador na sua rede?

Comment: Eu entendi. Só discordei quando você disse que ''não está la''. Veja a foto que postei do codigo. Está la, e está salvo. O problema é que o navegador não está ''puxando'' essa informação do código fonte.

Comment: O teste está sendo feito tanto no 192.168.1.220, quanto por outro computador que está conectado em rede. Os dois apresentam o mesmo problema no chrome

Comment: Não esta mesmo lá, olha as duas imagens, pelas duas que vc postou os HTMLs estão totalmente diferentes, o problema não tem nada haver com favicon, ou seja você deve estar salvando no seu computador, mas o endereço 192.168.1.220 é outro computador, ou seja vc salvou só na sua maquina local, entendeu?

Comment: Não amigo, o código fonte está apenas no 192.168.1.220. Todas as alterações estão sendo feitas neste computador (192.168.1.220). O codigo fonte está realmente diferente, o chrome não está reconhecendo o link para o favicon. este é o problema

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71237/discussion-between-amauri-and-guilherme-nascimento-p).

Comment: @Amauri esquece o favicon, olha os códigos HTML das duas imagens, estão diferentes, esta claro que não é o mesmo arquivo, entenda você deve estar salvando o home.php na sua máquina, mas precisa salvar na maquina 192.168.1.220 também, que presumo que é uma máquina diferente

Comment: tentando abrir o chat aqui, so um minuto